# Установка Reporting Services 2017 паралельно 2008r2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Есть SQL Server 2008r2 с установленными Reporting Services.
Хотим параллельно поставить SQL Server Reporting Services 2017 на этот же сервер, чтобы работали одновременно обе версии.
Возможно ли это? Где почитать об этом? 
Как перенести существующие отчеты с 2008й версии в 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте по порядку:

- Поставить две версии, да возможно, разворачиваете второй инстанс, туда же ставите SSRS, для поддержки работоспособности обеих придется делать отчеты и там, и там.
- Cуществующие отчеты можно проапгрейдить путем открытия в новой студии, НО! версии обратно **НЕ СОВМЕСТИМЫ**, все что вы перенесете на 2017, в 2008 работать не будут.